# .Net Core Foreign Key Field always null

Tags: .net-core, foreign-keys, relationship

We have a .net core api project. Foreign Keyed model always returning null from select queries.

DBContext is initialized with UseLazyLoadingProxies option.
Foreign key relation is defined in the table ContentTopic.

Foreign key is defined as ContentTopic->TopicId = Topic->Id

In the sample below Topic always return null.

```
services.AddDbContext<VaultContext>(options =>options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContext")));

[Table("ContentTopic")]
public class ContentTopic
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TopicId { get; set; }
    public long ContentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsInBody { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TopicId")]
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is your Id property on your Topic Entity of type long ?

Comment: Yes, it is long.

Comment: There are many foreignkey relations and all of them returning as null..!

Comment: I've tried replicating your issue, but I'm not getting any issues on my side. In your VaultContext do you have all the DbSet properties needed?

Comment: We have fixed the issue which was very weird! Actually we have defined the UseLazyLoadingProxies extension in the startup.cs but it was not the solution then we have called that extension from dbcontext in onconfiguring method and it worked!

Comment: Good to hear you've fixed it, however on my side when using LazyLoadingProxies I always configure them in Startup.cs without any issues.

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Comment: Strange but this is how we overcomed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UseLazyLoadingProxies extension must be called from DBContext in OnConfiguring method not from Startup.cs